# Javascript code is not executed after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

This is my "link":

```
%span{:id => "car_#{car.id}", :onclick => "add_car(#{car.id}"} Add
```

that leads on to here:

```
function add_trending(car_id) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/cars/add_car",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"car_id" : car_id},
    dataType: "html"
  });
}
```

in controller:

```
  def add_car   
    @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
    ...

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

and **add_car.js.erb**:

```
alert("YES");
```

But the alert window is not popped up. When I take a look at logs, I see there following:

```
Rendered cars/add_car.js.erb (0.0ms)
```

The javascript is just rendered, not executed based on logs. How is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the concreet response from ajax file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ajax request returns javascript you must set the `dataType : script` or use `$.getScript` function.

In this case you haven't any success callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at your network traffic client-side?  I'm guessing that you're sending this down to the client, but it doesn't know what to do with this result.  In fact, if that's your entire handler in jQuery, then it won't do anything with the response.  You need a success and/or failure handler in the options object passed to `jQuery.ajax`, or you need to attach one to the promise it returns.  In other words, you're probably getting the data back but not doing anything with it.